# Could someone please explain the difference between these expressions

Tags: networking, iptables, tcp, udp, filter

```
drop proto tcp and not (dst port 80)

pass proto tcp and dst port 80
```

Is there a difference between them?

Comment: It's tagged iptables but the rules aren't iptables rules. Maybe pf or else some frontend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the difference is simple.

- first rule immediately drops non-HTTP
- second rule immediately allows HTTP

Although it may trick you, these aren't even close. Because:

- there are several types of traffic on the server, first rule just prohibits it.
- in the same time it **does not** allows HTTP: whether or not HTTP will be allowed is determined by the subsequent rules or *chain policy*.
- second rule, on the other hand, explicitly allows HTTP and doesn't tamper with everything else.

There are rare conditions where you need rules like first, so stick to the second ones unless you are absolutely sure **why** you need first one.